# JavaScript: Capturing right click and disabling menu only within certain element

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, right-click

I have coded a jquery script where there is a small grid on screen and using drag and drop users can place tiles on the grid (snaps in place). Currently if you hover over a tile it fades in the option to rotate, but I would much prefer it if you could right click to rotate (making it more natural). I understand blocking right click completely is often frowned upon so was wondering if it was possible just within a particular element, then capturing that event, doing something in JS and disabling the context menu? - that works in every browser.

On a side note, currently I am using jQuery for effects and custom javascript for drag and drop, is it worth looking at a jQuery plugin for drag and drop?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For capturing the right click, you can use this jquery:

```
$('#gridID').bind('contextmenu', function(e) {
   // do stuff here instead of normal context menu
   return false;
});
```

This works in chrome, firefox, and safari.  <strike>Haven't tested IE</strike>.  Works in IE too.  Only caveat is it doesn't work in Opera apparently.  So if you can live with that...

Comment: This answer is invalid, contextmenu is triggered on right mousedown, not on right click.

Comment: A bit harsh and nit-picky to downvote an answer that works.  Maybe the wording is confusing, but even the Mozilla documentation says "right click" (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/contextmenu).  Regardless, the code is about simply capturing the "contextmenu" event of a browser and stopping it from showing the menu.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a fan of using the right mouse button on web pages. However, if you really want to do it, you could trap the right mouse button as described [here](http://www.rgagnon.com/jsdetails/js-0061.html). You could block the right mouse button (in other words return false in your event handler) conditionally if the mouse is over your grid cells.

Regarding your bonus question: [jquery ui has drag & drop functionality](http://ui-dev.jquery.com/demos/draggable/). It's probably easier to use that than rolling your own.

Comment: Many thanks, following your advice I've looking at "draggable" and found this http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/snap-to.html seems to be what I need for the dragging

Answer (score 0):

> "is it worth looking at a jQuery plugin for drag and drop?"

Only if you don't intend your application to be used on the iPhone O.S with safari, i.e. including iPad, see [Safari Web Content Guide: Handling Events](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/InternetWeb/Conceptual/SafariVisualEffectsProgGuide/InteractiveVisualEffects/InteractiveVisualEffects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008032-CH3-SW3)