# Video save issue with right click on video

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, css

Hello I am getting video from data base and i find one issue with video saving option

when user right click on video then user can able to save video in system space. what i want to do i want to stop option of right click on video on one user can able to save video with the help of right click. i want to know how can i stop right click event on video player 
here is a tag of video player bellow :

```
<video src='<%# "VideoHandler.ashx?id=" + Eval("ID") %>' width="220" height="200" controls="" preload=""></video>
```

I want to stop right click option on it.

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript: Capturing right click and disabling menu only within certain element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973321/javascript-capturing-right-click-and-disabling-menu-only-within-certain-element)

Comment: Why do you want to stop the right-click? The user will still be able to download and store the video. In fact, my Firefox displays a button in the toolbar whenever it plays a video via which I can download it. Even without that button, the user can simply choose to view the source of the website to see the URL of the video.

Comment: yes i want to control this but how can i stop it

Comment: You can't. You might be able to make it a bit harder, but you can't stop it.

Comment: @Vikas: You can't prevent the user from downloading the video. As a matter of fact, the user needs to download it to view it.

Comment: im ding that user can able to download it after paying because video is not free

Answer (score 0):

Create a short (10 second) video of something like a spinning dollar sign. Link to that video instead so that if the user right-clicks and then clicks "Save as", they just get the short spinning dollar video.

Alternatively you could implement an IHttpHandler that takes the incoming video stream and outputs it as a sequence of JPG images. That way, a user could only ever capture one frame at a time. The drawback with this is that it can make audio synchronisation difficult so I always include a link to the MP3 audio track and get the user to click that as well.

Hope this helps